# Trouble with object selection in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, enums

Currently building an app whereby the user can log in either locally or via google (will be expanded to other social sites). I'm using an enum array to hold the possible login methods. My user schema looks as follows:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  method :{
    type: String,
    enum: ['local', 'google', 'twitter'],
    required: true
  },
  local: {
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    projects: [
      {
        projectName: String,
        sessionLength: Number,
        timestamp: Date
      }
    ]
  },
  google: {
    googleId: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    projects: [
      {
        projectName: String,
        sessionLength: Number,
        timestamp: Date
      }
    ]
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

The following code is used to create the new user and save to the database after authentication by Google.

```
    let newUser = new User({
      method: 'google',
      google: {
        googleId: profile.id,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        username: profile.name.givenName
      }
    });
```

My problem is that newUser contains, as well as the correct google object, a 'local' object with a projects array. Below is how the newUser looks. I dont want it to include the local object. It also only seems to only appear if the projects property is an array, works as expected when projects is set to be a string. What am I doing wrong?

```
{ method: 'google',
  _id: 5a32aaa4c665b062df9c0d00,
  google: 
   { googleId: 'randomgoogleId',
     email: 'name@gmail.com',
     username: 'name',
     projects: [] },
  local: { projects: [] } }
```

Comment: You could simply pick the values you want to save to the database.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing by creating newUser?

Comment: Okay, could you send the full code where the you're creating a new user?  Also include the google response object in the source.